# Mass distribution integration exercise, I'm stuck.

Tags: integration

I have following exercise:

"A rod of length $l > 1$ has mass density $p(x) = 3x^{-1/2} * |x-1|$ . Other hints: the total mass $M = 8$ and $0 < x < l$ ."

"Determine $l$"

So that's the exercise, I've tried solving it and I come to the conclusion that $l=0$ but that's obviously wrong. Here are my calculations:

[image]

Can someone explain me where that I went wrong?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

Function total mass: $M = \int^b_a p(x)dx$

Mass density = $p(x)$

Comment: Is the answer 3 ?

Comment: @Mann Yes it is

Comment: Ok, let me write an answer. One minute!

Comment: Ah, never mind. Chinny has solved your problem. Take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the rod thin? I.e you only have to integrate the one dimension "x" in this case? In any case To integrate the equation
$$
\int_0^l x^{-1/2}|x-1| dx = \int_0^1 x^{-1/2}(1-x)dx + \int_1^l x^{-1/2}(x-1) dx
$$
Computing the integrals we get
$$
3\left[2x^{1/2}-\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}\right]_0^1 + 3\left[\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}-2x^{1/2}\right]_1^L
$$
(I changed l to L to make it look nicer)
Thus putting the limits in we get
$$
3(2-2/3) +\left(2L^{3/2} -6L^{1/2}\right) -3(2/3-2) = 8
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$
8+ \left(2L^{3/2} -6L^{1/2}\right) = 8
$$
Or
$$
2L^{3/2} -6L^{1/2} = 2L^{1/2}(L-3) = 0
$$
Now we are done as only one of the roots satisfy the condition on $L$ or in your terms $l$.

Comment: Why did you leave out the $3$? And I'm not quite sure what to answer to "Is the rod thin?". I know it has a mass so I don't think it's thin.

Comment: 3 is just a mutiplier. So does not affect the mechanics of the integral. As for "thin" I just mean that the wire has thickeness which can be ignored.

Comment: Check out the result to see if it helps..

Comment: If you say the multiplier does not affect the mechanics then won't I get the same results using your equation?

Comment: I changed the post.